# Effect size for Wilcoxon Rank Sum test

Tags: effect-size, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, scipy

I'm unsure how to calculate the effect size after applying a Wilcoxon rank-sum test. I'm using `scipy.stats.ranksums`, where the outputs are `z, p`. Looking at the implementation of the test, it seems `z` is assumed to be normally distributed - could I just calculate Cohen's d as discussed [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_cohen_d_equal_to_z_statistics_How_can_I_calculate_cohen_d_using_Z_scores)?

I'm confused since [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Effect_sizes) offers alternative effect sizes for these non-parametric tests, but then also, the article states that the Wilcoxon rank-sum and the Mann-Whitney-U tests are the same, while scipy clearly implements them quite differently. Unfortunately, I cannot apply the MWU test since some of my comparisons involve samples with zero variance which leads to errors with MWU but not rank-sums.

Comment: You can't assume that a *constant* column is has a sum of ranks that is normally distributed. Indeed scipy.stats.ranksums *doesn't handle ties*. Did you read the documentation for these functions? It's quite clearly stated.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you can show Kendall's rank correlation between the binary grouping variable and your numeric column. A test on this correlation will provide similar p value than the rank sum test.

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same question. According to  [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94280/how-to-convert-from-mann-whitney-u-to-z-or-other-effect-size) and Wilcox (p166) you shouldn't calculate Z and Cohen's D respectively because their calculation is based on the normality assumption.

Wilcox provides robust alternatives to Cohen's D (p166-170) including R code in his book. Got the book from my library. It is also available as e-book in both library networks I have access to.

http://store.elsevier.com/Introduction-to-Robust-Estimation-and-Hypothesis-Testing/Rand-Wilcox/isbn-9780123870155/

There are a couple of other posts in this forum asking very similar questions (effect size for [Wilcoxon](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30455/how-to-determine-the-effect-size-of-a-wilcoxon-rank-sum-test-in-r), [one sample Wilxocon](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23275/how-do-you-calculate-the-effect-size-of-one-sample-wilcoxon-signed-rank-test) or [Mann-Whitney-U](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94280/how-to-convert-from-mann-whitney-u-to-z-or-other-effect-size) tests just to name a few). You might like to look at those too.