# How to combine effect size of Wilcoxon signed rank test

Tags: meta-analysis, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am doing a Wilcoxon signed rank test on paired samples and it only reports effect size r and p-value. Since I am doing a meta-analysis and have calculated many effect sizes, I want to combine the effect size r in fixed/random model.

Is there any method to get SE or other variables to get weights to facilitate combining effect size r?

Comment: You ,ight be interested in my answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481079/calculating-effect-size-from-wilcoxon-w-value-how-to-get-the-z-value which although you are using a different test does apply to you I think